In a long table for a longitudinal study, how to loop efficiently across a large number of individuals?
I work on sexually transmitted diseases, such as gonorrhoea, and their possible consequences, such as ectopic pregnancy in women. I have a first dataset (df_gono) that contains whether and how many times patients have been diagnosed with gonorrhoea per year category. I have a second dataset (df_ecto) that contains whether and how many times patients have been diagnosed with ectopic pregnancy per year category. To that latter dataset, I would like to add a new variable that takes value 1 in all subsequent years, once she was diagnosed with gonorrhoea in a given year category.
I wrote a loop that works fine. The loop seems very simple to me, however, when applied to the real datasets with ca. 1Mio lines and ca. 600 000 unique patients, it takes > 3hrs. Any idea to make this more efficient and less time-consuming?
df_gono <- data.frame(pat_id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), year_cat = c("2000-2005", "2006-2010", "2011-2015", "2016-2020"), n_gono = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

df_gono

df_ecto <- data.frame(pat_id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), year_cat = c("2000-2005", "2006-2010", "2011-2015", "2016-2020"), n_ecto = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))

df_ecto


  for (i in c(unique(df_ecto$pat_id))) {
    gono <- df_gono[df_gono$pat_id == i, "n_gono"]
    if (any(gono$n_gono > 0)) {
      status_gono <- c(rep(0, each = 1, len = which(gono$n_gono != 0)[1]-1), rep(1, each = 1, len = dim(gono)[1]-(which(gono$n_gono != 0)[1])+1))
    } else {
      status_gono <- c(rep(0, each = 1, len = dim(gono)[1]))
    }
    df_ecto$gono_status[df_ecto$pat_id == i] <- status_gono
  }


df_ecto


It looks like you are using base--good choice. Hence, try
merge(df_ecto, df_gono, by = c("pat_id", "year_cat")) |>
  transform(status_gono = ave(n_gono, pat_id, FUN = cumsum))

giving
   pat_id  year_cat n_ecto n_gono status_gono
1       A 2000-2005      1      0           0
2       A 2006-2010      0      0           0
3       A 2011-2015      0      1           1
4       A 2016-2020      0      0           1
5       B 2000-2005      0      1           1
6       B 2006-2010      1      0           1
7       B 2011-2015      0      0           1
8       B 2016-2020      1      0           1
9       C 2000-2005      0      0           0
10      C 2006-2010      0      0           0
11      C 2011-2015      0      0           0
12      C 2016-2020      0      0           0


No loops needed. This should take seconds on your full data.
library(dplyr)
df_ecto |>
  left_join(df_gono, by = c("pat_id", "year_cat")) |>
  mutate(status_gono = cumsum(n_gono), .by = pat_id)
#    pat_id  year_cat n_ecto n_gono status_gono
# 1       A 2000-2005      1      0           0
# 2       A 2006-2010      0      0           0
# 3       A 2011-2015      0      1           1
# 4       A 2016-2020      0      0           1
# 5       B 2000-2005      0      1           1
# 6       B 2006-2010      1      0           1
# 7       B 2011-2015      0      0           1
# 8       B 2016-2020      1      0           1
# 9       C 2000-2005      0      0           0
# 10      C 2006-2010      0      0           0
# 11      C 2011-2015      0      0           0
# 12      C 2016-2020      0      0           0

